# Running assembly 68k on Mac M1

Tags: macos, assembly, apple-m1, apple-silicon, easy68k

I am learning 68k assembly at school, but I am working on a Mac M1, and I struggle to find a solution.
I tried installing VMs with UTM, but the execution is really slow as it has to generate a graphical interface too.
I also tried using Wine64 with Easy68k, but it didn't work as well.
That's why I was wondering if there was any solution to the problem.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the problem is. UTM/QEMU is easily the simplest way to emulate a m68k environment on Apple Silicon (e.g., Mac Studio) systems. It's also almost certainly going to be the most stable and fastest solution. You failed to specify which OS you are hosting. Anything that involves graphics is going to be slow by modern standards because UTM/QEMU doesn't support GPUs.